# Gravar dados em classes filhos diferentes Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, realtime-database

Estou tentando gravar alguns dados em outra classe de filho no firebase, porem sem sucesso, segue código.
Porem sem sucesso, quando eu executo a aplicação primeiro são gravados os dados cliente, e logo em seguida os dados ete sobrescrevem os dados cliente.

```
private void salvar() {
  Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
  Ete ete = new Ete();
  try {
    cliente.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    cliente.setNome(in_nome_empresa.getText().toString());
    cliente.setCnpj(in_cnpj.getText().toString());
    cliente.setEndereco(in_endereco.getText().toString());
    cliente.setCidade(in_cidade.getText().toString());
    cliente.setCep(in_cep.getText().toString());
    cliente.setEstado(spn_estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
    databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(maxId + 1)).setValue(cliente);

    ete.setFabricante(spn_fabricante.getSelectedItem().toString());
    ete.setModelo(spn_ModEte.getSelectedItem().toString());
    databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(maxId + 1)).setValue(ete);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    MensageBox.Show(this, "Erro", "Erro ao Salvar Dados" + ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso porque você está escrevendo na mesma referência (`databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(maxId + 1))`), o que está tentando fazer?

Comment: obrigado, consegui resolver, adicionando databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ETE"); antes do setvalue da ETE

Answer (score 0):

```js
private void salvar(){

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            Ete ete = new Ete();
        try {

            cliente.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            cliente.setNome(in_nome_empresa.getText().toString());
            cliente.setCnpj(in_cnpj.getText().toString());
            cliente.setEndereco(in_endereco.getText().toString());
            cliente.setCidade(in_cidade.getText().toString());
            cliente.setCep(in_cep.getText().toString());
            cliente.setEstado(spn_estado.getSelectedItem().toString());
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CLIENTE");
            databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(maxId + 1)).setValue(cliente);

            ete.setFabricante(spn_fabricante.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ete.setModelo(spn_ModEte.getSelectedItem().toString());
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ETE");
            databaseReference.child(String.valueOf(maxId + 1)).setValue(ete);

          } catch (Exception ex){
            MensageBox.Show(this, "Erro", "Erro ao Salvar Dados" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

resolvido.